# Verb て-form + もない meaning

Tags: grammar, particles, negation

Example sentence, which is a response to someone who is talking like they were already invited to a party:

まだ誘ってもないのに｡

I'm not able to wrap my head around the grammar used in what looks like a pretty simple sentence:

1. Why is the verb in its conjunctive form?
2. What is the ない negating? Is it negating the verb 誘う, or is there a ある verb here that is being negated? Or something else entirely that I'm not seeing?
3. Is that the only location where the も particle could fit in naturally? Assuming it means something like "even" here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have missed the -teiru form. Let's look at this step by step:

- **誘う**: a transitive verb, "to invite (someone)"
- **誘っている**: the -teiru form of 誘う to express the resultant state, "has invited"; See [When is Vている the continuation of action and when is it the continuation of state?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3122/5010)
- **誘っていない**: negative form of 誘っている, "has not invited"
- **誘ってない**: a colloquial version of 誘っていない "hasn't invited"; See: [What is the difference between ～してる and ～している?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/51818/5010)
- **誘ってもない**: added も meaning *even*, "has not even invited"
- **誘ってもないのに**: added [のに](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42408/5010) for regrettable feeling

So the entire sentence means:

> まだ誘ってもないのに。
> I haven't even invited you/them yet (but you/they are here)!

---

> Is that the only location where the も particle could fit in naturally? Assuming it means something like "even" here.

Another way to add も in this context would be 誘っていもしないのに, but this is much less common. For the grammar, you may find [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/100239/5010) interesting.