# Are you supposed to not pronounce the "い" in います when reading out sentences or speaking?

Tags: pronunciation

New learner of two weeks. Noticed in my software course after hours of using it that the い  seems to never pronounced or maybe I don't hear it? Is this a rule that when reading only "mas" should be heard?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33463/9831

Answer (score 1):

Why did you think that?
It's impossible not to pronounce it.

Please pronounce it.

---

そこにいます。

in Romaji: sokoni imasu.

Perhaps it's hard to hear for foreigners when they are sequential, like "に（ni）" and "い（i）".

But, being Japanese, I think I'm pronouncing it. It never sounds like it's missing.

Comment: i can hear the い being pronounced on other sentences that use い but just with います specifically i can never hear it being read out in rosetta stone.

Comment: I don't know because I didn't actually hear it, but I think you probably just didn't catch it.

Comment: wanted to make sure it wasn't being slurred together like "vous avez" in french or something.

Comment: @verve edit my answer.

Comment: don't know romaji but you're japanese so you would know that い is pronounced always. Definitely making sure to do it now.

Comment: @verve Note that there are other sentences where it can be dropped like やっています → やってます, but usually that is reflected in how it is written like I just did. In the sentence shingo provided such elision is not possible though. Anyways, you should provide an audio clip (perhaps using some screen/audio capture software).