# Use of たこと with te-form verbs

Tags: meaning, words

I've come across the following sentence

> 叫んでたことを知ってたよ。

I know that you can do `past tense verbs + こと` but I've never seen `te-form verbs + たこと`. So what does it mean using te-form in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

たこと is nonsensical. It is not a word that I know of. (タコとエビ makes sense but consists of three words. Just a facetious aside)

叫んで**い**たことを知って**い**たよ -> 叫んでたことを知ってたよ

Please see

[Just like "ら抜き" is there also "い抜き" such as "見ている" --> (い抜く) --> "見てる"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33463/30454)

[ておく → とく in other contexts; similar 2-kana to 1-kana shortcuts?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30995/30454)

Comment: Gotcha. So it's basically the te form + いる in past tense. I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks!